# Wordpress menu items not being saved

Tags: wordpress

I'm having problem with WP, I've developed theme on my localhost (MAMP), and everything looked good in Appearance > Menus, I have something like 8 top level menu items, and each had 5-10 subitems. When I uploaded theme onto server, and wanted to add menu items and click save - new items weren't saved. In total, now I have ˜18 menu items (top and sub level), and can't add any new ones.

Does it have something to do with `max_vars` in PHP config? I've tried to increase `POST` max_vars size to 4096, but isn't working. Anyone have a clue?

Comment: I've deleted my answer as it was totally wrong, hopefully you'll get more attention if the question is unanswered. Googling it brings loads of people who have fixed this issue with server side suhosin config changes, ask your host about those to see if they are relevant to your setup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just finished resolving the same issue. I had 90 menu items and couldn't add any more. I found the answer on this Wordpress support ticket:

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14134

The problem was that the apache configuration was limiting the number of POST items. Each menu item counts as a POST item, so the solution was as simple as increasing the Maximum Post Limit. Since my site is hosted on a shared server, this was as easy as adding `php_value max_input_vars 10000` to my .htaccess file. I'm sure you could also change this in your php.ini file. Hope this helps!

Comment: Just wanted to add a comment — I had a very similar problem, and adding `php_value max_input_vars 5000` to my .htaccess file had no effect. Turns out that an old security plugin, WP Firewall 2, was causing the problem. If someone else has gotten this far, and you have that, disable it!